# asp.net 4.5 Code First Classes And Displaying Items In A Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview, ef-code-first

I have created the following Classes and then used the Entity First approach to successfully create a database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HR_Test_v0_1.Models
{
    public class simStaff
    {
        [Key]
        public int simStaffId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must enter a first name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } 
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must enter a last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public simStaff simHoursRecorded { get; set; }
        public simPayRate simPayRate { get; set; }
    }

    public class simHoursRecorded
    {
        [Key]
        public int simHoursRecordId { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DayWorked { get; set; }
        public int HoursBooked { get; set; }
        public bool AuthorisedToPay { get; set; }

        public int simStaffId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<simStaff> simStaff { get; set; }

    }

    public class simPayRate
    {
        [Key]
        public int simPayRateId { get; set; }
        public double RatePerHour { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAppliesFrom { get; set; }

        public int simHoursTypeId { get; set; }       
        public ICollection<simHoursType> simHoursType { get; set; }

        public int simStaffId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<simStaff> simStaff { get; set; }
    }

    public class simHoursType
    {
        [Key]
        public int simHoursTypeId { get; set; }
        public string HoursType { get; set; }
        public simPayRate simPayRate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

My context class is as follows:

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext() : base("name=HRTestContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<simStaff> simStaffs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<simHoursRecorded> simHoursRecordeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<simPayRate> simPayRates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<simHoursType> simHoursType { get; set; }

}
```

And the relevant extract from my Repository.cs file is as follows:

```
    public IEnumerable<simPayRate> GetPayRate
    {
        get
        {
            return context.simPayRates;
        }

    }
```

In the ListView I have the the code below. The InsertItemTemplate works, however, in the ItemTemplate when I enter Item.simHoursType, I was hoping to see an option for HoursType from the simHoursType entity:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
 <td><%# Item.RatePerHour %></td>
 <td><%# Item.DateAppliesFrom.ToShortDateString() %></td>
 <td><%# Item.simHoursType %></td>

 <td>
 <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" runat="server" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
   <InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td><input id="RatePerHour" runat="server" 
           value="<%# BindItem.RatePerHour %>" /></td>
    <td><input id="DateAppliesFrom" runat="server" 
           value="<%# BindItem.DateAppliesFrom %>" /></td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddHoursType" 
                        runat="server"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        SelectMethod="GetHoursType" 
                        DataTextField="HoursType"
                        DataValueField="simHoursTypeId"
                        SelectedValue="<%# BindItem.simHoursTypeId %>"
                        AutoPostBack="false" />
     </td>
     <td>
       <asp:Button CommandName="Insert" runat="server" text="Add" />
       <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
     </td>
     </tr>
     </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Can I change the way the classes are created so I can enterItem.simHoursType.HoursType, or if not what should I do to display the HoursType?

Comment: Are you wanting to see`HoursType` for each item in the `simPayRate.simHoursType` collection? It looks like `Item` is an instance of `simPayRate`?

Comment: Hi @trix0412, in the ItemTemplate I was hoping to type for the third item, Item.simHoursType.HoursType to show the item that was selected in the InsertItemTemplate using the DropDownList. Unfortunately when I type Item.simHoursType I don't get the option to select any of the fields in simHoursType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code First Conventions are incorrect, they should be as follows:

```
public class simStaff
{
    [Key]
    public int simStaffId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must enter a first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must enter a last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<simHoursRecorded> simHoursRecorded { get; set; }
    public ICollection<simPayRate> simPayRate { get; set; }
}

public class simHoursRecorded
{
    [Key]
    public int simHoursRecordId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DayWorked { get; set; }
    public int HoursBooked { get; set; }
    public bool AuthorisedToPay { get; set; }

    public int simStaffId { get; set; }
    public simStaff simStaff;
}

public class simPayRate
{
    [Key]
    public int simPayRateId { get; set; }
    public double RatePerHour { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAppliesFrom { get; set; }

    public int? simHoursTypeId { get; set; }       
    public simHoursType simHoursType { get; set; }
    public int simStaffId { get; set; }
    public simStaff simStaff;
}

public class simHoursType
{
    [Key]
    public int simHoursTypeId { get; set; }
    public string HoursType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<simHoursType> simPayRate { get; set; }
}
```

Then it is necessary to use include in Repository.cs as follows:

```
    public IEnumerable<simPayRate> GetPayRate
    {
        get
        {
            return context.simPayRates.Include("simHoursType");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason you aren't able to do this is because `Item.simHoursType` is actually an `ICollection` of `simHoursType`. In order to access `HoursType` you would have to access a single item in that collection. For example: `Item.simHoursType[0].HoursType`.